# How can I set the aperture in A mode with a D lens on my Nikon D90?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, nikon-d90

I use Nikon 35mm f/2d lense on my Nikon D90 but I am unable to change aperture of lens.

I have the aperture on the lens set to f22 and locked, I can change aperture with the buttons and the change is reflected on how is the shutter speed calculated. But when I take photo for example with aperture set to 22 (A mode) it is overexposed (pure white).

I get same result of photo (M mode) for settings A-2 S-400 / A-22 S-400 (A is aperture S is shutter speed).

Aperture ring of the lens works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are describing sounds like a physical problem with the camera or lens.

There is a metal lever on the back of a D lens that closes the aperture, and it should move freely. It sounds like either the camera is not moving the lever properly, or that part of the lens mechanism is broken.

You could troubleshoot the problem by testing the lens on another automatic Nikon camera (auto film cameras control the aperture in the same way as the D90), and by trying another D lens on your camera.

Comment: It does sound like a physical problem. There is probably one other thing worth testing. You say that the lens is set to f/22 and locked. It is (just) possible to apparently set and lock the aperture, but it is a fraction of a millimetre out. Try removing the lens, unlocking the aperture, rotate the aperture to another value, reset it back to f/22, making sure it is fully rotated; relock and reattach the lens. It is most unlikely that this will help, but if it does it will save you other investigations and possible costs.

Comment: @ChrisWalton I tried that but it didn't help so I take it as my lense is damaged - or at least I made that assumption 2 years ago :) (Sorry for replying so late and thanks for your advice)